# Value used as both output and (non-reference) input in a chain of methods

Tags: delphi, parameters, undefined-behavior, method-chaining

Consider the following minimal example of method chaining, where a floating-point variable is set (using an `out` parameter) by an early method and then passed (using a `const` parameter) to a later method in the chain:

```
program ChainedConundrum;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  ValueType = Double;
  TRec = record
    function GetValue(out AOutput: ValueType): TRec;
    procedure ShowValue(const AInput: ValueType);
  end;

function TRec.GetValue(out AOutput: ValueType): TRec;
begin
  AOutput := 394;
  Result := Self;
end;

procedure TRec.ShowValue(const AInput: ValueType);
begin
  Writeln(AInput);
end;

var
  R: TRec;
  Value: ValueType = 713;

begin
  R.GetValue(Value).ShowValue(Value);
  Readln;
end.
```

I initially expected this to print the floating-point number `394` (in some format), but it doesn't (necessarily); when I build the program using the 32-bit compiler of Delphi 10.3.2, the program prints `713`. Stepping through the program using the debugger confirms that the initial, pre-`GetValue` value of `Value` is passed to `ShowValue`.

However, if I build this using the 64-bit compiler, `394` is printed. Similarly, if I change `ValueType` from `Double` to `Int32`, I get `394` in both versions. `Int64` yields `394` in 64-bit and `713` in 32-bit. Strings yield the updated value. Classes work just like records. Class methods, however, as opposed to instance methods, always give me the updated value. And, of course, abandoning method chaining (`R.GetValue(Value); R.ShowValue(Value)`) does the same.

Not surprisingly, if I change the `AInput` parameter of `ShowValue` from a `const` (or undecorated value) parameter to a `var` parameter, I always get the updated value.

My conclusion is that either

1. it is not allowed to both set and pass a variable in a chain of methods like this, or
2. there's a bug in the compiler.

My question is: which is it? And if it isn't allowed, where does the documentation state this? I have so far not been able to find the relevant passage. (The phrase "sequence point" seems very rarely to occur anywhere near the phrase "Delphi" on the WWW.)

Comment: This feels like a compiler bug to me. The compiler is likely treating the `Value: ValueType = 713;` declaration like a constant. It probably doesn't consider that `GetValue()` is using an `out` parameter that could alter `Value` before `ShowValue()` is called, so it thinks it is OK to just pass the initial constant value as-is instead when it really is not OK to do so. Odd that everything works with `var` though, since `out` is treated exactly like `var` for non-managed types. You should [report this to Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com) and let them decide.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks for your reply. My initial feeling was too that this must be a bug. Replacing `out` with `var` in `GetValue` changes nothing (still the old, wrong, value). (But changing from `const` to `var` in `ShowValue` makes it all work as exepcted. That's natural, since `@Value` is never changed at all.)

Comment: Did you try disabling optimization? It definitely looks like an optimizer bug.

Comment: So this "only" happens to 64bit datatypes on x64? `Comp` and `Currency` should show the same behaviour then.

Comment: @AmigoJack: I have only seen it in 32-bit, and it happens for `Single` as well.

Comment: @Olivier: Actually, it happens both with and without optimization.

Comment: Interesting q, +1.  Somewhat reminiscent of https://delphisorcery.blogspot.com/2014/10/generics-and-variance.html which was linked to another q here in the last day or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone who has commented on this issue here or elsewhere agrees that this either "feels like" or "clearly" is a compiler bug.

I've created issue [RSP-29733](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-29733) at the Embarcadero Jira.

Turning to possible workarounds, notice that the issue seems to be that an old *value* of a variable is used by the compiler. Hence, the problem arise when the *value* is changed close to the use of the variable.

However, the variable's *address* isn't changed, so if you pass the variable by reference instead of by value, the problem disappears. One way is to use a `var` parameter when the value is passed the second time, even though you don't need that, or even want that semantically.

Hence, a more natural approach seems to be to use a [`const [Ref]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Constant_Parameters) parameter:

```
procedure ShowValue(const [Ref] AInput: ValueType);
```

This has the same semantics as an undecorated `const` parameter but forces the compiler to pass the variable by reference, thus avoiding the bug.

Comment: The problem seems to be the fact that value of your constant is set upon entering of that specific code line. But since you have code line with two commands where one of them changes the value of variable from which the constant is assigned you end up with old value instead of updated one like you would expect. But of you go and split your two command into separate lines `R.GetValue(Value).ShowValue(Value); R.GetValue(Value).ShowValue(Value);` then the result will be as you would expect it to be.

Comment: @SilverWarior: Yes, I made that remark in my Q! "And, of course, abandoning method chaining (`R.GetValue(Value); R.ShowValue(Value)`) does the same." :)